# Умное слияние двух таблиц в sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблицы. Т1:

```
Предмет    | номер группы
Яблоко     | 1
Груша      | 1
Монитор    | 2
Клавиатура | 2
Чайник     | 3
```

и Т2:

```
Предмет | номер группы
Яблоко  | 1
Персик  | 1
Кактус  | 2
Монитор | 3
Мышь    | 3
Чайник  | 4
```

Нужно слить их в общую таблицу, сохранив сгруппированность, но переназначив индексы во второй таблице, чтобы получилась таблица Т3:

```
Предмет    | номер группы
Яблоко     | 1
Груша      | 1
Персик     | 1
Монитор    | 2
Мышь       | 2*
Клавиатура | 2
Чайник     | 3
Кактус     | 4*
```

То есть, перебирая по порядку вторую таблицу.

- Видим, что яблоко уже есть в Т1, причем с тем же индексом группы - пропускаем.
- Видим, что персика нет - добавляем, при этом даем номер группы тот же, что у яблока, т.к. они с ним в одной группе в Т2 и он есть в Т1, т.е. единицу.
- А вот, например, у мыши пришлось номер группы изменить. В таблице Т2 он равен 3. Но в Т1 группа компьютерных принадлежностей идет под номером 2. Это мы понимаем, т.к. есть пересечение по строке с монитором. В Т2 они в одной группе, а в Т1 у монитора номер группы - 2, значит переназначили на 2
- Кактус идет с группой 2 в Т2, но двойка уже занята в Т1, причем, у нас нет повода думать, что это та же группа, т.к. нет общих элементов у второй группы в Т1 и Т2, поэтому дали кактусу еще не занятый номер 4.
- С чайником из Т2 уже становится понятно. Он и так есть в Т1, поэтому пропускаем (хотя эта строка бы нам пригодилась, если бы попался в Т2 какой-нибудь тостер - 4 и мы бы поняли, что нужно в Т1 вставлять его с номером группы 3, как и чайник).

Надеюсь, ход мысли донес относительно прозрачно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select subj,
       coalesce(new_num, n1,
                dense_rank() over(order by n1, n2)+max(new_num) over()
               ) num
  from (
    select coalesce(t1.subj,t2.subj) subj, t1.num new_num, t2.num n2,
           first_value(t1.num) over(partition by t2.num order by t2.num desc, t1.num desc) n1
      from Table1 t1 full join Table2 t2 on t2.subj=t1.subj
  ) X
 order by num
```

Внимание: работа запроса чувствительна к порядку сортировки NULL значений, который отличается на разных СУБД. Запрос выше приведен для MS SQL. Для postgresql порядок сортировки во всех over() надо заменить на противоположный ([пример на postrgesql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/13f82/4)).

Comment: @downvoters пожалуйста указывайте причину минуса на корректно работающих ответах в комментариях

Comment: Эх, жаль раньше не встретился ответ. Пришлось своими культяпками воять. Раза в 4 больше по объему, еще и со временной таблицей. Очень уж поверхностное у меня знание SQL, но понадобился в проекте на C#

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов Ну любое самостоятельное решение уже хорошо. В этом деле просто знания не достаточно, нужен опыт, огромный. А это приходит только с годами самостоятельных попыток ну и подсматривания интересных приемов, как тут, например ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as
(select * from t1 full join
(select num num1, subj subj1, (select num  from t2 where num = t.num group by num having count(*) >1
and exists(select 1 from t1 where t2.num=t1.num)) num2  from t2  t) t2
on t1.subj=t2.subj1)
select 
coalesce(subj,subj1), case when subj is null 
then 
case when num2 is not null and exists (select 1  from cte cte1 where num is not null and cte1.num1=cte.num2 and cte.num1=cte1.num1) 
          then (select min(num)  from cte cte1 where num is not null and cte1.num1=cte.num2 and cte.num1=cte1.num1) 

else (select max(num) from cte)+rank() over(partition by num, case when num2 is null then 1 else 0 end order by num1)  end

else num end
from cte
order by 2;
```

Comment: добавление розы в T2 в группу с кактусом (2) в результате выполнения получаем NULL и у розы и у кактуса. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3a5f0/1

Comment: @Mike, уже все забыл. :-) Поправил на скорую руку.